# Using Ember to write a canvas based game

Tags: javascript, canvas, ember.js

I'm new to Ember, and I'm currently experimenting with using Ember to write a canvas based game. This game will have an extremely slow refresh rate (it's essentially turn based, so there's no need to get a huge FPS).

Each model has a significant amount of view side rendering (to calculate trajectories etc etc), and I really like the Ember data models and usages.

The way I'm currently working is that for each model object in the collection, I call the method "draw" in a view, and pass the canvas context in as an argument. It then draws itself in the appropriate place on the canvas, relative to the center point.

I'm adding click events to it at the moment, and I was thinking about having a modal dialogue come up when you click on an object. The problem is, where does the code for this go? I currently added it in the model, but (especially as I can't access the router), it really doesn't belong there. Similarly, my models are currently far too cluttered for my liking with rendering code.

Where should the click events (on canvas coordinates) and canvas drawing code go? I think ideally, I should be using a decorator pattern, but I'm not sure how to fit that into the Ember framework.

EDIT: Code samples: This is the main view, which loads the canvas initially:

```
Space.CanvasView = Ember.View.extend({
  tagName: 'canvas',

  didInsertElement: function(){
    this._super();
    var context = this.draw();
    this.get('controller').send('draw', context)
  },

  draw: function(){
    canvas = this.get('element');
    context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var w = $(window).width();
    var h = $(window).height();
    canvas.width = w;
    canvas.height = h;
    context.fillRect (0, 0, w,h);
    context.centerX = w/2;
    context.centerY = h/2;
    return context;
  }
});
```

Then, in the main parent view:

```
Space.System = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  //attributes and various other model methods that do some maths

  draw: function(context){
    var drawRadius = this.get('radius');
    // 30 lines of drawing on the canvas
    context.fill();
    this.get('orbitals').forEach(function(orbital){
      orbital.draw(context);
    })
  },

  setContext: function(context){
    var sys = this
    this.get('orbitals').then(function(){
      sys.clickHandlers(context);
      sys.draw(context);
    })
    window.onresize = function(e){sys.draw(context)};
  },

  clickHandlers: function(context){
    system = this;
    context.canvas.addEventListener('click', function(ev){
      system.get('orbitals').map(function(orbital){
        if(orbital.withinOrbital(context, ev.clientX - context.canvas.offsetLeft, ev.clientY - context.canvas.offsetTop)){
          console.log(orbital);
        }
      })
    }, false)
  }
```

Similarly, each Orbital then implements it's own draw method, taking the context as an argument that draws it onto the canvas.

Comment: can you post parts of the relevant code, so we can have a look at it and propose an answer?

Comment: @intuitivepixel, added some code samples. I'm not sure if Ember is really the right solution for this, but I'm mixing it with a more 'traditional' setup of forms and such for different types of actions, so it would be nice to be able to tie the existing model structure in.

Comment: The `MV*` architectural design pattern is _not_ what you use for games. It doesn't work well for games most of the time _especially_ if you use a framework like Ember that is geared towards web applications with many forms and things. Stuff like templates is pretty meaningless in a game context. You asked so there you have it - **Ember is not the right framwork for this**

Comment: **For modal dialogues and where the code should go**, see:

 http://hawkins.io/2013/06/ember-and-bootstrap-modals/

 https://github.com/ebryn/ember-modals-playground/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/views/modal_view.js

http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/modal-views-can-we-agree-on-a-best-practice/707

Comment: Thanks @BenjaminGruenbaum. I was beginning to suspect that, from the difficulty of forcing my code to meet that model. If it's the wrong thing, it's the wrong thing, I'll rip ember out (at least of those areas). The advantage of having this as a personal playground rather than a commercial product!

Comment: MVC may not be the right architecture, but I think it gets easier when you:

1. Use Components instead of Views so that you can keep state more easily.
2. Imagine the interactions like a web app.  Clicking somewhere (the attack button, for example) triggers an action.
3. Use css to position things.  This makes buttons and other dialog options way easier.  I made a canvas-based dialog system once and it was not fun to build or use.
4. Use Ember Data to keep track of game stats, even if it's just on localstorage.

Good luck out there!

Answer (score 1):

I know this has already been discussed in the replies above but I would also say that Ember is not the tool for game development. But on the plus side there seems to be plenty of JS game engines out there. Take a look here https://gist.github.com/bebraw/768272 for a list of a bunch of them.

Much like other areas of JS there seems to be a billion of them and I am not experienced with them so I can not give a recommendation, but take a look at a few and see which make the most sense to you. Let me know if you find any good ones... I would be interested in what you find.

Comment: Not to beat this one to death but I came across a few other resources that seem to contain a little more information. http://html5gameengine.com/ This one has a smaller list which may be nicer to get started with and also contains some ratings and features listed. Then this site http://www.html5gamedevelopment.com/html5-engines seems to be dedicated to HTML5 game development which probably has a ton of resources. Hope this helps.